# Not able to enter data in a field using Selenium with java/javascript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to enter data in a field whose display is block **(HIGHLIGHTED IN YELLOW)**. Here is my code snapshot:

[image]
[image]

**I've tried following codes:**

**1st using java------>**

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@class='form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']")
public WebElement errorNotifRcpntOrdrng;

CamWizCHOR.errorNotifRcpntOrdrng.sendKeys(CommonConstants.EmailId);
```

So, I got this error after running this code:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='form-control ng-pristine
>   ng-valid ng-touched']"}

**2nd using javascript------->**

```
String js = "arguments[0].style.display='block'"; 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, CamWizCHOR.errorNotifRcpntOrdrng);

JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", CamWizCHOR.errorNotifRcpntOrdrng);

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='abc@test.com.au';", CamWizCHOR.errorNotifRcpntOrdrng);
```

After running this code, I got same error message as above:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='form-control ng-pristine
>   ng-valid ng-touched']"}

Please have a look and suggest how can I enter data in this field.

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `String js = "arguments[0].style.display='block'"; ` to  `String js = "arguments[0].style.display='inline'"; `

Comment: thanks, I tried but same error appears.

Comment: try `@FindBy(xpath="//input[@class='errornotification']")`

Comment: there is already another webElement with same name, so to avoid that I used @class. please check updated snapshot(highlighted in yellow is the one I want to try with)

Comment: Both have same classes and attribs, try with `@FindBy(xpath="//input[@class='errornotification'][1]")` change it to [2] if it doesn't work

Comment: I tried with [1] then it enters data for 1st Webelement but not for 2nd webelement and when I changed to [2] then it doesn't do anything and errors out.

Comment: TRY THIS `@FindBy(xpath="(//input[@class='errornotification'])[1]")`, try with numbers 1 and 2